# Box2D unusual bug. Why does +0 prevent an error?

Tags: c++, box2d

I found a very strange bug which I don't understand. Perhaps someone could shed some light.

### The Problem

I'm using box2D to run a physics simulation. One of the things in the simulation is a body which has its linear damping set every frame, to a float between 0 and 2. On each body, the following line is called.

```
body->SetLinearDamping(value);
```

When enough of these bodies are added (about 500) the the program quietly breaks (somehow), and memory usage goes up from ~50mb to 300mb in a few seconds. At this same point only 1 or 2 of the bodies are rendered and only for a few seconds. This is presumably because world.query returns incorrect results.

I did manage to determine the cause of the program-death memory spike. In the box2d's solve function the contact manager adds thousands of pairs. The excess memory almost exclusively comes from b2Contact::Create.

Edit: I should have mentioned, the increase in memory its self begins after a certain number of calls to b2World::Step. It's probably about 10,000 or so. I don't know how to detect the problem from within the program so I cannot determine if it is the same number of steps each time.

### The Bug

Initially I thought I might be misusing SetLinearDamping somehow. I tried to change the range of the values so I simply added +1 to them. This actually solved the problem completely, I stress test it by just adding about 10,000 objects and pushing them around.

So next I made this value smaller, trying to determine the minimum value I could add. +0.01f worked just as well as +1, so just before doing + numeric_limits::min() I tried +0. So now my code is:

```
body->SetLinearDamping(value+0);
```

This fixes the program. Upon discovering this I have actually developed the program a lot more, and it runs completely stable. I would have thought the compiler would optimize this out. Does this actually have any function in c++ and how could that prevent a problem in box2d?

Comment: *and it completely stable* -- Unless you know the reason for the bug initially, it isn't "completely stable".  Anytime things like this happen, never mask the error by doing changes that seemingly don't do anything logically.  Put the error back into the program, and actually diagnose the issue.

Comment: Well the issue seems to be changing the linear damping value of a body before step is called, every time step is called. This was determined after much diagnosis. The resulting error is within box2d, I believe it is prone to getting stuck trying to solve non recursive algorithms, as I read searching similar problems. Mostly I am curious as to the functional difference passing value vs value+0.

Comment: does set linear damping have overloads?  is there access from a debugger inside that function?  I would start by examining exactly what is passed in, and what the function then has as the value.

Comment: The function just sets a member variable. 
`m_linearDamping = linearDamping;`I should mention it takes a float32

Comment: @MushyShaman Sounds more like memory corruption is occurring, and adding / removing that line is just moving the bug to another part of the code.  That's why you should bring the error back and actually fix the problem.

Comment: Could you go into memory corruption, its causes and effect or perhaps provide a resource? By the way, I'm investigating it right now. I had actually forgotten about it until I remembered to ask this question :)

Comment: Memory corruption can occur for many reasons.  One reason is overstepping array boundaries by accessing an array (or any linear sequence) in an out-of-bounds entry.  Another is accessing data from memory that is not valid (which is really related to the array issue).  There could be a whole host of other reasons, such as a bad or incomplete build of your code running, thus structures and other items are misaligned or wrong.  So the real genesis of the error may have occurred long before that line of code you identified -- it's just that the line of code exposes the bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon a lengthy amount of time spent stepping through code, I have determined the cause and the solution. For anyone having similar problems in box2d, you need to check for NaN's. I had forgotten c++ even had these, and I must say I feel like an idiot that this went over my head.

The problem here was that occasionally, the function which provided the value would return nan. Passing nan as the linear velocity to a box2d function causes a ripple of nans through my program, you know how nans be.

After all the x and y values of my bodies end up as nan, they were essentially all in the same place. This causes collision manager to have to generate thousands of pairs, as each colliding body must be checked against every other colliding body.

Finally, adding 0 to a NaN apparently returns 0. So in answer to the original question, *what is the functional difference between value vs value+0* :

**In the occasion that value is Not a Number, value evaluates to 0.**

Comment: Have you tested and confirmed that adding 0 to a NaN is 0? I believe that adding any float to a NaN is supposed to always return a NaN. I wonder if maybe that's dependent on the optimization level to some compilers. I ran some tests myself on adding 0 to NaN. I tried both quiet NaN and signaling NaN. Always got NaN as the result. Didn't try using different compiler optimizations but I thought I've come across some mention of math optimizations possibly producing unexpected results like you're suggesting.

Comment: To be honest, I had different results in debug and release configurations. I'm using VS 2015 and I believe it may be something to do with my funky project set up.... and Microsofts hatred for standards.
Either way I fixed the code, handling the NaN values appropriately in the functions they were coming from. Adding 0 would be a really bad and unreliable practice for handling them, as I quickly discovered :)